# Cannot ingest null values in Azure Data Explorer scalar columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-data-factory

I use Azure Data Factory to ingest data into Azure Data Explorer and the ingestion keeps failing because of data conversion issue.

Kusto table definition:
`.create table Overview (..., Age: real)`

Exception happens when I try to ingest `null` value into Age column.

> Operation on target CopyOverviewFromBlobToADE failed: Failure happened
> on 'Sink' side.
> ErrorCode=UserErrorKustoWriteFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Write
> to Kusto failed with following error: An error occurred for source:
> 'DataReader'. Error: 'One or more errors
> occurred.'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.KustoConnector,''Type=Kusto.Ingest.Exceptions.IngestClientException,Message=An
> error occurred for source: 'DataReader'. Error: 'One or more errors
> occurred.',Source=Kusto.Ingest,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
> 'Age' contains an invalid value 'null'. Cannot convert 'null' to type
> 'Double'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input
> string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'

It says here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/
*All non-string data types include a special "null" value, which represents the lack of data or a mismatch of data. For example, attempting to ingest the string "abc" into an int column results in this value.*

How can null values be ingested then?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by removing the Age property from a record that has it as 'null'.

So in My case the source is Blob with json files and in case the document has valid real type value the json would be { ... "Age": "2.5", ... }, in case the Age is missing I have to get rid of the Age property in the document altogether.

It turns out in ADF you can get rid of the property with the following derived column expression in the data flow:
iif(equals(Age, 'None'), **toString(null())**, Age).

Answer (score 0):

On ingestion ADX does not recognize string literal 'null' as an indicator of a null value.
An empty string or simply omitting the value/field will result in a null value being ingested.